# Iterative Alliterative Additive Array Antics

Tags: code-golf, array

I honestly don't know what the point of this sort of calculation would be, but it should make fun golfing. Shortest code wins.

### Input (in no particular order)

- An array of integers, `a` (All elements will be integers less than the length of the array.)
- An index therein, `i`
- An iteration count, `n`

### Processing

- Store a number `x` with initial value of `0`.
- Do the following steps `n` times:

  1. Add the current value of `i` to `x`.
  2. Decrement `a[i]`.
  3. If `a[i]` is negative, increment it by the length of `a`.
  4. Set `i` to `a[i]`.
- After the iterations, add the final value of `i` to `x`.

### Output

After doing the above process, your program should output the final value of `x`.

### Example (n=5)

```
a                     i   x
2,0,0,5,5,6,7,5,8,5   0   0
1,0,0,5,5,6,7,5,8,5   1   0
1,9,0,5,5,6,7,5,8,5   9   1
1,9,0,5,5,6,7,5,8,4   4   10
1,9,0,5,4,6,7,5,8,4   4   14
1,9,0,5,3,6,7,5,8,4   3   18
```

The program outputs `21`.

### Test Case Generator

```js
function newTestCase() {
    var a = Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 25).fill(0);
    a = a.map(Math.random).map(e => e * a.length).map(Math.floor);
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
    for (var x = 0, n = 0, aa = [...a], ii = i; Math.random() * a.length >= .5;) {
        n++;
        x += ii;
        aa[ii]--;
        if (aa[ii] < 0) aa[ii] += a.length;
        ii = aa[ii];
    }
    return {a, i, n, shouldOutput: x + ii};
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="console.log(newTestCase());">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```ruby
->a,i,n{i+(1..n).map{i=a[i]+=a[i]<1?a.size-1:-1}.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ1MnrzpTW8NQTy9PUy83saA60zYxOjNWG0zaGNon6hVnVqXqGlrpGtbqFZfm1v4vKC0pVkiLjjbSMQBCUyA00zEHkhY6prEggdj/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 71 bytes

```python
def f(a,i,n):x=0;exec"x+=i;a[i]+=len(a)*(a[i]<1)-1;i=a[i];"*n;print x+i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYdBCsMgEAC/Ijlp3IIGbEo2viR4kFbpQthKyMG@3hgGhpnyP78/nlr7pCyyjEDAaqneYKrpPVTtCeNGQfs9sYxqlPetVj0skr8bh5GxHMSnqJpaltsEpuM6T5i7X@ACCAPCqXYB)

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>86</s> 82 bytes

```
{a,i,n->var x=0;var y=i;(0..n).map{x+=y;a[y]+=if(a[y]<1)a.size-1 else-1;y=a[y]};x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xC4MwEIV3f8WNCUbRgm0xRujYqUPH0uEGI6GaSkzFVPztNpHeg/e944Z3r7ftlN4m7ECW5KrtxRh0DHzajUJSB4LYFmSK6aSe0MAsMh7ohOIkS1NN0x6HZY6F4/hwz1goSUKocorpqL5NkkPTjR7ciXBY@bxu8qOhR6UJmnYsYe@u7tYo3dYUlgj8DH6znSaSqP93N0kOLPMqvI7s5P3MCsogY1BQGq3bDw)

---

### Ungolfed

```
{a, i, n ->
    var x=0
    var y=i
    (0..n).map{
        x+=y
        a[y]+=if(a[y]<1) a.size -1 else -1
        y=a[y]
    }
    x
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>95</s> 83 bytes

```r
function(a,i,n){for(j in 1:n){F=i+F-1
i=(a[i]=a[i]-1+(a[i]-1<0)*sum(a|1))+1}
F+i-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcdBCoMwEIXhvafIcqaZgFOwlWK2uYS4CEJgBCNYXVXPHqfID9/jrSWZzpW053GTJUMkoYy/tKwwGcmGP/qCFxscV@Ih9jL4P44t3NvV@PjuM8SDES2fVbDi@CwJRnhSrTXai95qSw0SK@UC)

Takes `i` as a 1-based index, so it requires some adjustment to account for that.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>57</s> <s>56</s> 55 bytes

*Saved one byte thanks to @Lynn.*

```js
a=>n=>g=(i,x=0)=>n--?g(a[i]-=a[i]?1:1-a.length,x+i):x+i
```

Takes input in currying syntax in the format `f(a)(n)(i)`.

### Test Cases

```js
f=
a=>n=>g=(i,x=0)=>n--?g(a[i]-=a[i]?1:1-a.length,x+i):x+i
;
console.log( /*21*/ f([2,0,0,5,5,6,7,5,8,5])(5)(0) )
console.log( /*2066*/ f([18,26,9,26,58,53,35,28,0,47,44,6,24,11,66,48,63,64,3,19,67,55,59,35,37,22,41,8,51,44,3,58,58,9,31,29,20,63,43,19,53,28,40,70,20,46,3,69,34,63,49,29,42,69,26,49,37,26,41,62,7,3,66,55,27,59,9,2,36,24,61,6,7])(63)(26) )
console.log( /*1182*/ f([58,3,43,19,8,8,50,24,31,10,8,17,23,2,8,19,19,45,9,46,7,4,6,31,33,19,8,18,37,11,57,28,35,20,22,35,42,38,7,2,48,28,5,17,54,35,5,35,29,9,22,39,27,49,62,40,0,48,52,42,40,24,26])(46)(39) )
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>66</s> 63 bytes

The first argument is the length of the array.

*Thanks to [Justin Mariner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner) for saving 3 bytes.*

```c
f(l,a,i,n,x)int*a;{for(x=i;n--;x+=i=a[i]+=l*!a[i]-1);return x;}
```

Getting negative after decrement means it is zero before that.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtRCoMwEES/zSm2QiHRDWjBtrDkJNaPkDZlQdMSLATEs6eRB48ZmHH67VzOXs5okTFgUhzWxtLmP1Em01HQmtjYkafWzM3pCLpXqTVM8bX@YoDUMu253GCxHKQSm6iO5sYJDGwX7ApD4Yq34jsOO4nqG8vGy/r8fIQawcu@Q3AIxYNSJPb8Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
def f(a,i,n):x=i;exec"a[i]=i=~-a[i]%len(a);x+=i;"*n;print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1EnUydP06rCNtM6tSI1WSkxOjPWNtO2ThfEUM1JzdNI1LSu0AZKK2nlWRcUZeaVKFT8T9OINtIxAEJTIDTTMQeSFjqmsToKBjoKppr/AQ)

Similar to XCoder's, but makes use of simultaneous assignment, and python's delightful negative modulus, plus re-ordering some instructions to eliminate the extra addition.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 87 bytes

I went with a recursive method for this

```
int r(int[]a,int i,int n){return n>0?(i=a[i]>0?--a[i]:(a[i]=a.length-1))+r(a,i,--n):0;}
```

[see IDEone here](https://ideone.com/MoY6kE)